# How to insert module in product.tpl file in opencart 2.x?

Tags: module, opencart2.x

I want to display a module in product page. How i can insert the module on product.tpl file in opencart 2.x?

Answer (score 0):

For example,if you want to display **Specials** module on product page, you need to do the following steps

1. In opencart admin panel Go to **Extensions > Modules > Specials** (If not installed then install it.Click Edit button at the right).
2. Enter Module Name as **special-products** (put any name to recognize it).
3. Give limit,height,width & make Status as Enabled.
4. Click Save button.
5. Now Go to **System > Design > Layouts** and edit **Product** layout. (for Opencart 2.1.x Go to Design > Layouts)
6. Click on add module button at right corner.
7. Choose **"Specials > special-products"** for Module, Select **Position** and enter **Sort Order** (e.g  "Content Bottom" for Position and 1 for "Sort Order")
8. Click on save button.

Yo will see on product page **Specials module** is added.